# How to read Swift logs to trace down error?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview, crashlytics

I'm working on screen with 3 tableviews, I'm experiencing some unexpected problem which is causing app crash. and its happening unpredictably. followings are logs received in crashlytics.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  AbbeySwift                     0x104fff728 PickUpDestinationVC.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 4312364840 (PickUpDestinationVC.swift:4312364840)
1  AbbeySwift                     0x104fffee4 @objc PickUpDestinationVC.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 4312366820 (<compiler-generated>:4312366820)
2  UIKitCore                      0x1a44f1648 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 724
3  UIKitCore                      0x1a44bf0c8 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2524
4  UIKitCore                      0x1a44dc51c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 348
5  UIKitCore                      0x1a47e7398 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2468
6  QuartzCore                     0x1a4cecdf4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 288
7  QuartzCore                     0x1a4cf3398 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 520
8  QuartzCore                     0x1a4cfe6e8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 140
9  QuartzCore                     0x1a4c49d7c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 416
10 QuartzCore                     0x1a4c73f40 CA::Transaction::commit() + 728
11 QuartzCore                     0x1a4c751f0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1a19f187c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1a19ebf50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 604
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1a19ec498 __CFRunLoopRun + 960
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1a19ebba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
16 GraphicsServices               0x1b8751598 GSEventRunModal + 160
17 UIKitCore                      0x1a42dd2f4 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052
18 UIKitCore                      0x1a42e2874 UIApplicationMain + 164
19 AbbeySwift                     0x104f61e44 main + 16 (AppDelegate.swift:16)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a16ca568 start + 4
```

Can somebody point what sort of problem is it. PickUpDestinationVC has max 702 lines but logs are giving 4312364840 this line num.

Here is code of tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == self.w3wTV{
            Crashlytics.crashlytics().log("Creating W3w element: "+String(indexPath.row)+" and total count: "+String(w3wPlaces.count))
            let cell:SelectLocationTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SelectLocationTVC", for: indexPath) as! SelectLocationTVC
                cell.placesSearch.isHidden = true
                cell.w3wSearch.isHidden = false
                cell.lbNear.text = "Near " + (self.w3wPlaces[indexPath.row].nearPlace ?? "")
                cell.lbWord.text = self.w3wPlaces[indexPath.row].words
                cell.lbDistance.text = String((self.w3wPlaces[indexPath.row].distance ?? 0)) + " KM"
                return cell
        }else if tableView == self.recentTV{
            let cell:SelectLocationTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SelectLocationTVC", for: indexPath) as! SelectLocationTVC
            Crashlytics.crashlytics().log("Creating Recent element: "+String(indexPath.row)+" and total count: "+String(recentPlace.count))
            cell.placesSearch.isHidden = false
            cell.w3wSearch.isHidden = true
            cell.lbLocation.text = self.recentPlace[indexPath.row] //self.resultArrayNames[indexPath.row]
            cell.onFavoriteTapped = {
                if self.favPlaces.contains(self.recentPlace[indexPath.row]) {
                    self.showToast(message: "Alreay added as favorite", controller: self)
                } else {
                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    defaults.removeObject(forKey: "savePlace")
                    defaults.removeObject(forKey: "savePlaceIDs")
                    self.favPlaces.append(self.recentPlace[indexPath.row])
                    self.idFavPlaces.append(self.idRecentPlace[indexPath.row])
                    defaults.set(self.favPlaces, forKey: "savePlace")
                    defaults.set(self.idFavPlaces, forKey: "savePlaceIDs")
                    self.favoriteLocationTV.reloadData()
                    self.lbFav.isHidden = false
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
        else if tableView == self.selectLocationTV{
            let cell:SelectLocationTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SelectLocationTVC", for: indexPath) as! SelectLocationTVC
                Crashlytics.crashlytics().log("Creating Search element: "+String(indexPath.row)+" and total count: "+String(arrSearch.count))
                cell.placesSearch.isHidden = false
                cell.w3wSearch.isHidden = true
                cell.lbLocation.text = self.arrSearch[indexPath.row]
                cell.onFavoriteTapped = {
                    if self.favPlaces.contains(self.arrSearch[indexPath.row]) {
                        self.showToast(message: "Already added as favorite", controller: self)
                    } else {
                        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                        defaults.removeObject(forKey: "savePlace")
                        defaults.removeObject(forKey: "savePlaceIDs")
                        self.favPlaces.append(self.arrSearch[indexPath.row])
                        self.idFavPlaces.append(self.idSearch[indexPath.row])
                        defaults.set(self.favPlaces, forKey: "savePlace")
                        defaults.set(self.idFavPlaces, forKey: "savePlaceIDs")
                        self.favoriteLocationTV.reloadData()
                        self.lbFav.isHidden = false
                    }
                }
                return cell
        }
        else  {
            let cell:FavoriteLocationTVC = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FavoriteLocationTVC", for: indexPath) as! FavoriteLocationTVC
            Crashlytics.crashlytics().log("Creating Favorite element: "+String(indexPath.row)+" and total count: "+String(favPlaces.count))
            cell.lbLocationTitle.text = /self.favPlaces[indexPath.row]
            cell.onFavoriteTapped = {
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.removeObject(forKey: "savePlace")
                self.favPlaces.remove(at: (indexPath.row))
                defaults.set(self.favPlaces, forKey: "savePlace")
                self.favoriteLocationTV.reloadData()
                if self.favPlaces.count == 0{
                    self.lbFav.isHidden = true
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not clear, have you checked with exception break point?

Comment: many times, but unable to recreate it